# How to differentiate change transaction from actual transaction in bitcoin raw transaction template?

Tags: transactions, rpc, bitcoin

I'm trying to create my own display of the blockchain and I encounter an understanding problem. I'm using txindex=1 in bitcoin.conf to have access to non-wallet information on transactions but when I decode a rawtransaction I cannot make the difference between the change and the amount of the transaction.

Here a random example (with change) from the testnet:

```
"txid" : "979e9c84a9ce7e18e38b883eaba4078cd21e26ef5d13eba15aebeb355d42f5d5",
    "version" : 1,
   "locktime" : 0,
   "vin" : [
    {
        "txid" : "593b3c92ca20a789fadbfe563139c3cc89824e05557c68e247418b13ddd6e5ed",
        "vout" : 1,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "304402202b6be66d4a4ac12ea93f678cb66903ba266c8f74bfccd0c01cd6ad2225d180d002200f9daf5c7a96cbddaa74d9fc449bec7a5f9ed6d61091d35148adad72e930214e01 04280cf692411203d1e133789692f7121735dabe290a5e626d6d16c6aa9b44950628ae448dcdf9e0f19fd3859df8f3a1cb947b2be5091a93edbe37bb4c99b160c5",
            "hex" : "47304402202b6be66d4a4ac12ea93f678cb66903ba266c8f74bfccd0c01cd6ad2225d180d002200f9daf5c7a96cbddaa74d9fc449bec7a5f9ed6d61091d35148adad72e930214e014104280cf692411203d1e133789692f7121735dabe290a5e626d6d16c6aa9b44950628ae448dcdf9e0f19fd3859df8f3a1cb947b2be5091a93edbe37bb4c99b160c5"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    }
],
"vout" : [
    {
        "value" : 40.00000000,
        "n" : 0,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 f35a10d09c9a09bbce7aacdd0888c151866affcf OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex" : "76a914f35a10d09c9a09bbce7aacdd0888c151866affcf88ac",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "pubkeyhash",
            "addresses" : [
                "n3hgPYQArNYj8fkxW369qT16k7i3r9oSrQ"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value" : 9.89980000,
        "n" : 1,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 f5dbc72c2b7170e51469b8b46700567d1e2eee5e OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex" : "76a914f5dbc72c2b7170e51469b8b46700567d1e2eee5e88ac",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "pubkeyhash",
            "addresses" : [
                "n3vw8VmfuEwWuVsD9KoWiNzCX7EsrjRVr7"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Is there an easy way to find out which one is the "good" one ? 40 BTC or 9.9 BTC ? I tried to display recursively the "vin" transaction id to find out more information but never found a clue to help me. May be am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no good answer to this question, I found a duplicate on stackexchange: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/how-to-find-the-change-sender-address-given-a-txid

tl;dr: anything you will do to guess which public address is the sender's/receiver's (based on the amounts of both inputs and outputs) will stay a guess because the bitcoin core want to protect this information.